# How to print hour values in an hourly report in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building hourly report from SQL Table CONFIRMATION via SQL Query. Query absolutely runs fine and gives proper results as follow:

```
SELECT DATEPART(hh, CONFIRMATION.DATECOMPLETE) AS hour, sum( CONFIRMATION.QUANTITY) Units
FROM  CONFIRMATION 
WHERE  CONFIRMATION.DATECOMPLETE >= '11/18/2015'
GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,   CONFIRMATION.DATECOMPLETE)
```

I want to change Hour to have follwoing instead of hour number:

```
Hour                  Units
10:00 - 11:00         4
11:00-12:00           8
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When putting parts of dates together using concatenation, `datename()` is much better than `datepart()`:

```
SELECT (DATENAME(hour, c.DATECOMPLETE) + ':00-' +
        DATENAME(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, c.DATECOMPLETE)) + ':00'
       ) as period,
       SUM(c.QUANTITY) as Units
FROM CONFIRMATION c
WHERE c.DATECOMPLETE >= '2015-11-18'
GROUP BY (DATENAME(hour, c.DATECOMPLETE) + ':00-' +
          DATENAME(hour, DATEADD(hour, 1, c.DATECOMPLETE)) + ':00'
         );
```

In addition:

- Use ISO standard date formats.  Either YYYY-MM-DD or YYYYMMDD.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the datetime hour component into a string to format the `10:00-11:00`. You can then calculate the end time by adding 1 to the hour component and modulo 24 to wrap around at midnight.

```
CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEPART(hh,CONFIRMATION.DATECOMPLETE)) + ':00-' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEPART(hh,CONFIRMATION.DATECOMPLETE)+1) % 24) + ':00'
```